# How to check if a column value contains integers in oracle

Tags: oracle, integer

Need a query that has to check whether resulting columns have integer.

Comment: The question is similar but not a duplicate. Checking for number is not the same as checking for integer.

Comment: @Rene Agreed. This is not a duplicate. In fact, in terms of the information sought, the approach(es) to the answer, and the probable use case, it is distinct from the other question. That designation should be removed.

Answer (score 10):

First you must know if the value is a number. If it is in a column of type number you don't have to worry about that. To check if the value is an integer you can use the trunc function. This will take the decimal values off.

```
if trunc(value)= value then
   -- we have an integer
else
   -- we don't
end if;
```

Comment: If it's a numeric column, there is also `if mod(value,1) != 0...`, which works great for me.

Comment: Thanks WAF..  Cool logic to work on..  thanks again !!